# Create a directory at user's home directory throught a shell script with command mkdir ~/adirectory

Tags: shell

I am trying to create directory at user's home directory using a shell script. The script has following line:

```
mkdir -p $path # where path=~/adirectory, path is obtained from env
```

but instead of creating it at user's home directory i.e. `/home/auser/adirectory`, it creates a directory named `~` at current working directory and places `adirectory` inside it.

Update:

Thanx to `Jonathan Leffler` for helping out. Below is the working snippet of my code:

```
function init() {
  if [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "" ]; then
    export PROJECT_DIR=$HOME/projects
  fi

  mkdir -p `expand $PROJECT_DIR`
}

function expand(){
  echo `sh -c "echo $1"`
}
```

As `Jonathan Leffler` pointed, the problem was with `tilde expansion`. Using `sh -c $path` worked for me.

Comment: Which shell, on which system?  You say `$path=~/adirectory`; did you look to see which value it has?  The assignment should be `path=~/adirectory`.  What do you get from `echo "$path"` before the `mkdir` command?  You also need to scrutinize [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) to see whether that explains why you get the result you did (it probably does). Note that the shell expands (or not) `~`; `mkdir` simply sees it as the first character of a pathname, and it's a path relative to the current directory since it does not start with `/`.

Comment: I even tried mkdir -p $(echo $path), which does not work either

Comment: Note that `/bin/sh` is often `bash` in disguise, but it can be `dash` or another shell.  Using Bash as `/bin/sh` changes its mode of operation.  Tilde expansion occurs before variable expansion, so if the variable value contains `~`, it remains as `~`; that's consistent with the original problem report.  It isn't clear how you get `echo $path` to give the full pathname, though — that is wholly inconsistent with the claimed behaviour. Can we see the result of running: `sh -x -c 'path="~/adirectory.v2"; echo "$path"; mkdir -p $path'`? The name chosen is different; it'll create the `~` directory.

Comment: Then we need to see the result of: `sh -x -c 'path=~/adirectory.v3; echo "$path"; mkdir -p $path'` too.  This should expand the `~` in the assignment, so the `echo` should give the full pathname, and the directory should be created as intended (modulo permission problems and/or pre-existence).  As noted, your question reports the behaviour for the version with quotes around the assignment; then it claims the behaviour for the version without quotes around the assignment.  I think  you may be confused about something — or I'm _very_ confused about what you're doing.

Comment: the code works fine, it actually creates `adirectory.v3` at the home directory. I tried hard coding `mkdir -p ~/adirectory` which also works fine, but getting the value of `$path` from env and creating directory from it does not work. Should I use `eval`? i dont think using eval is good option

Comment: "The code works fine" doesn't help; I've given two lots of code which should behave differently, and asked you to show the output (meaning: add it to the question), and you've not done so. I don't know how you're getting the value of `$path` from the environment, so I can't tell you how to fix the problem. If 'the environment' contains a `~` and not the full path, you need to do the equivalent of `eval` somehow, though I agree that you should aim to avoid `eval` when you can. It depends in part on whether you trust the environment, and how much damage will be done if the trust is misplaced.

Comment: Note that `sh -c "mkdir -p $path"` would be equivalent to `eval` (but doesn't actually invoke `eval` as a command).  The launching shell would expand `$path` to `~/adirectory.v4/sub-dir` or whatever, and the launched shell would then expand the string containing that `~` as part of its normal processing.

Comment: Thanx @JonathanLeffler for helping out.

Comment: The *right* thing to do is not use `~` in the value of `path` at all.

Comment: @chepner - how to determine the home directory of current user then?

Comment: You can use the environment variable `$HOME`. However, since `~` would be expanded in the example you showed anyway, it seems the real issue is that whoever is setting the value of `path` is not doing so in a shell environment, meaning they should be specifying the path explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with tilde expansion. Using sh -c $path worked for me.

```
function init() {
  if [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "" ]; then
    export PROJECT_DIR=$HOME/projects
  fi

  mkdir -p `expand $PROJECT_DIR`
}

function expand(){
  echo `sh -c "echo $1"`
}
```